# Library of terms for interface (interactions and designs)

Tags: interaction-design, interface

I'm studying interaction design (via a Swedish uni) so am having some difficulty finding ***English*** terms for different interactions and interface designs. Terms like lightbox popup and modal overlays.

*A couple of days ago I found myself miserably failing in describing a feature on Amazon (gone now, must have been an A/B test) where, after you add an item to the basket, a window slides out from the right, displaying what's in the basket, and with a button navigating to the checkout page.*

<sub>*What would I call a function like this?</sub>

---

**Q.** What I really want to ask though, is if you know of any library where I can find a list of terms and explanations for different types of interactions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more to check out.

apple  https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/

android  https://material.io/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a comprehensive list, but here are a few relevant articles:

- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-design-cheat-sheet/
- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/typography-terms-ux/
- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-brand-terms-defined/

Comment: Thank you :) I found this list as well which is pretty handy: https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/user-interface-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

all of the above links as well as https://pttrns.com/ & https://uimovement.com/ to present Interaction mock.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the relevant parts into your answer? Link rot and all that.